# Opening hyperlinks (URLs) from QGIS HTML widget

Tags: qgis, html, hyperlink, qgis-custom-widgets

I recently got aware that you can now create a custom HTML widget by which you can replace the regular attribute form when you click the Identify features button in QGIS.

As far as I can see it is a mix of a few code languages like HTML, JavaScript and PyQGIS (QGIS expressions).

How do you know what languages that you possibly mix? I need to know because I usually are searching the internet for help.

How can I open hyperlinks in combination with QGIS expressions that i am using? I cannot find the proper function or write the right syntax.

Here is the code as it looks now...

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <title>Materialize Sandbox</title>
    </head>

    <style> 

body { 
background-color: white!important; 
font-family: sans-serif;
width: 50px;
} 

table { 
border-collapse: collapse; 
} 

th { 
font-size: 7px;
padding: 2px;
padding-top: 10px;
background: whitesmoke;
color:red;
text-align: left;
}


tr { 
border: 2px solid white; 
} 

tr:nth-child (odd) {
background:grey!important;
}

td { 
font-size: 12px;
white-space: nowrap; 
padding: 5px; 
}

td.h2{
font-size: 10px; 
float: left!important;
font-weight: bold;
background:grey;
}

td.bold { 
font-size: 12px; 
font-weight: bold; 
} 

td.gap { 
background-color:white; 
padding:1px; 
} 
.table tr:nth-child(odd){ 
background: #b8d1f3;
}

.table tr:nth-child(even){
background: #dae5f4;
}

</style>

<table class="table">
<th><h1><script>document.write(expression.evaluate("'Lokalplan'  || ' '  || plannr"));</script>
</h1></th>
<th></th>

<tr><td class="bold">Plannavn:</td><td><script>document.write(expression.evaluate("\"plannavn\""));</script></td></tr>
<tr><td class="bold">Anvendelse generel:</td><td><script>document.write(expression.evaluate("CASE when \"anvendelsegenerel\" is null then 'Anvendelse ikke reguleret' ELSE \"anvendelsegenerel\" end"));</script></td></tr>
<tr><td class="bold">Zonestatus:</td><td><script>document.write(expression.evaluate("CASE when \"zonestatus\" = 'Byzone' then \"zonestatus\" else 'Landzone' END"));</script></td></tr> 
<tr><td class="bold">Dato vedtaget:</td><td><script>document.write(expression.evaluate("substr( \"datovedt\" ,7,2)  || '.'  ||   substr( \"datovedt\" ,5,2)  || '.' || substr( \"datovedt\" ,1,4) "));</script></td></tr>
<tr><td class="bold">Dato offentliggjort:</td><td><script>document.write(expression.evaluate("substr( \"datoikraft\" ,7,2)  || '.'  ||   substr( \"datoikraft\" ,5,2)  || '.' || substr( \"datoikraft\" ,1,4) "));</script></td></tr>
<tr><td class="bold">Link til lokalplan:</td><td><script>webbrowser.open(expression.evaluate("\"URL\""));</script></td></tr> 
</table>


             </html>
```

It is especially the latter part of the code that is tricking me.

What I want is to make QGIS able to open a hyperlink from the HTML table row.
Example below:

`<tr><td class="bold">Link til lokalplan:</td><td><script>webbrowser.open(expression.evaluate("\"URL""));</script></td></tr>`

Though, I cannot find a proper script or command that opens the URL. `webbrowser.open` does not work, apparently.

Can anybody help out?

Comment: You need to focus on one question per 'question' at the moment you have two.  Also just quickly scanning your html , you seem to be missing some `body` tags

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in webbrowser. Since you are displaying HTML, you can create a clickable link

```
<script>document.write("<A HREF='" + expression.evaluate("\"URL\"") + "'>" + expression.evaluate("\"URL\"")) + "</A>";</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to load a custom URL:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    let layer = expression.evaluate("lower(@layer_name)");
    window.location.replace("http:/host.domain.tld/"+layer+"/");
</script>
```