# QGIS Web View in Form does not support JavaScript ES6

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am trying to display a custom made slider with several images and files for my GIS elements.

Example URL: https://eudala2.getxo.eus/slidergetxo/?width=500&height=500&codtipoexp=LMO&codruta=islas&idelem=prueba

The problem comes when I add the website as Attached Control and Display it as Web View in the Integrated Document Viewer.

[image]

The slider is not loaded properly:

[image]

And it leaves a bunch of console errors pointing to no ES6 compatibility (async functions, etc.).

[image]

I tested it out in several versions including 3.34.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the slider, but if you want to just display the selection, you could try using an `HtmlWidget` and display your code there (and adjust it to display the selection). Try looking at the answers [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371820/opening-hyperlinks-urls-from-qgis-html-widget)

Comment: @DrorBogin it's a NodeJS app that is running in our servers. The images/documents are obtained in the server side and the web displays the slider. I tried using the HtmlWidget as you suggest, inserting the code of my slider on it but I get the same problem and console is showing same ES6 compatibility errors.

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using?